# Как понизить уровень проверки?

Tags: javascript, безопасность

При вот таком коде:

```
var result = ctx[functionName].apply(ctx, arguments);
```

получаю ругань в консоли:

> SecurityError: The operation is insecure.

**Как можно обойти этот момент?**

вот полный код для ясности:

```
function makeErrorWrapper(ctx, functionName) {
    return function() {
      var result = ctx[functionName].apply(ctx, arguments);
      var err = ctx.getError();
      if (err != 0) {
        glErrorShadow[err] = true;
        opt_onErrorFunc(err, functionName, arguments);
      }
      return result;
    };
  }
```

Comment: Mozilla Firefox?

Comment: @Khipster он самый

Comment: )))))))) смешно

Comment: ff 45.4 esr не выходит воспроизвести ошибку. Вы её видите в консоли браузера, или фаербага, или ещё гдето?

Comment: @Arnial в firebug

Comment: @Arnial моя версия ff 49.0.2

Comment: Я правильно понимаю что ctx это WebGLRenderingContext?

Comment: @Arnial да вы все правильно поняли, это код из книги, по отзывам у американцев проблем с этим не было.

Comment: @perfect, для любой _functionName_?

Comment: вообще в вопрос стоит добавить [mcve] - сам по себе код вполне рабочий, все зависит от параметров и браузера в котором это все работает

Comment: @Grundy , это очень сложно так как этот код webgl использует, могу исходник дать. https://cloud.mail.ru/public/6rbk/6NgdPXqc5 папка 5 файл TexturedQuad.html . Там все в комплекте.

Comment: @perfect, таки стоит выкинуть все лишнее, там в итоге не большой кусок должен остаться

Comment: @Grundy , в функцию контекст для рендеринга попадает, такое эмулировать довольно сложно.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48222/discussion-between-grundy-and-perfect).

Answer (score 0):

В общем дело было не в этой функции. А в том что были подключены картинки через относительный путь, а сам html файл был запущен локально с файловой системы. Через http этой проблемы нет.

Comment: а где по ссылке на политику можно найти про этот url? И непонятно как ты решил проблему

Comment: @Grundy, а там написано что проверяется подлинность документа (например картинки) по принадлежности к своему домену. критериями является имя домена, порт и тд. Детально я так и не разобрался. Но точно помогает если картинку положить в один каталог с htmlкой.

Comment: а в какой момент вообще бросается исключение? как только src присваиваешь? или когда эту картинку рисовать пытаешься?

Comment: да как только в src попадает относительный путь

Comment: странно все это

Comment: не странно, рисуется в канвас, а это HTML5, а он еще сырой. и я подозреваю что через этот канвас можно поиметь систему. думаю потом это допилят.

Comment: нет, раньше падало, если именно с другого домена загружаешь, а не по относительному пути

Comment: не факт но может быть этот код нормально заработает если он на хостинге будет, а не как у меня локально на файловой системе. пока я это не проверял.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48260/discussion-between-grundy-and-perfect).